# Hi I am struggling to solve a problem of binary search.. Here If i looking for one value, its ok.. but how can I do with whith multiple values?

Tags: c

here it works for one value, but how can i modify for multiple values?
like m=10, its ok.. but what should I do for multiple values, like m=10,2,5....

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 1, 5, 10, 4, 11, 15, 13};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    int right = n - 1;
    int left = 0;
    int middle, m = 10;
    while (left <= right)
    {
        middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (arr[middle] == m)
        {
            printf("found");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (arr[middle] < m)
            left = middle + 1;
        else
            right = middle - 1;
    }
    printf("didnt found");
}
```

Comment: nope .. cant I do this without using the function ?? I mean using a loop.. like I declare an array, m[] and I store values there.. like m[]={10,3,2}.. then I will check for every single value, that it is an array arr or not...

Comment: OT: I'll recommend `qsort` instead of doing your own sorting

Comment: Please apply indentation to help with understanding your code. Ideally, explain your code to help even more. Describe what you want to do. What would be the desired output? Do I get correctly that you have a list to search for in the array? For the given example of input "10,2,5", would the desired output be "found, found, found"? What would be the desired output for "10, 12, 5"? Maybe "found, found"? Or "found, not found, found"? OR "found, found, didnt found"? Or "didnt found all"? Or "found some"?

Comment: you can't do this for multiple values in a single pass. The algorithm works by splitting the sorted array into smaller and smaller sub-arrays. So sooner or later two different search-values will end up in different sub-arrays and then the algo wont work

Comment: If the number of values in the array is a lot more than the number of values you're looking for; you could sort the values you're looking for (e.g. `m = { 2, 5, 10, ...}`, find the first/smallest value, then ignore that part of the array when looking for the second value; then ignore more of the array when finding the third value, etc. In extreme cases (huge array with the number's you're looking for close together) this could be much faster than just searching for each number individually.

Comment: actually what I am trying to do is, trying to get search for multiple values.. 
suppose I have an array called arr.. I stored some values there.. like 10,15,16,18.... now I wanna search is, the value of 16,18 are presented there.. if I got those values, will be printed found.. 
so now, I wanna store 16,18 in an array and name it suppose ar.. no what I want, that to loop the array and look for those value, are they in the arr array ...

Comment: i rewrite the code.. but the problem is if the element was not in the first array, it will print no, for that element.. 
but if the element is in second or third position in the array , which is 2nd array, its printing yes.. 
so I don't why this is happening ...
please check the code..

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/79e36e29